# Blending more than 3 materials in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to make an auto landscape material with 4 materials. If I use 3 materials it blends as expected but if I try blending a 4th I get the default texture when I compile. There are no compilation errors.

The really odd thing is that my normal maps and displacement maps still blend properly. If I put a solid color into the base color output and light the scene I can see that the materials are where I want them to be, but if I put the blended base color I get the default texture with no normals/displacement.

Is this expected behavior or is it a bug? I'm not using landscape layer blend since I want to set the masks procedurally.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. If anyone is looking for a solution to this, the issue was I needed to set the sampler source to "Shared:wrap" on my texture samples.